# Getting back response message with 200

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to figure out how to dump the actual status message coming back from an endpoint I'm hitting but I can't quite see how to get it.

Currently, I'm hitting the endpoint and using a try/catch block. In the try portion, I hit it, flush the session and create a 200 message. When I hit this now I get my success message below:

```
$authService = new AuthService();
$authLogout = $authService->logout($logoutToken);

Session::flush();

$response = json_decode(response()->json(['success' => 'success'], 200);
dd($response);
```

So I know it's successful, but I want to return the JSON decoded message that the endpoint actually sends back with a 200 status.

How can I do that properly?

Update: Var dump on response()

```
object(Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse)#762 (9) { ["data":protected]=> string(21) "{"success":"success"}" ["callback":protected]=> NULL ["encodingOptions":protected]=> int(0) ["headers"]=> object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag)#760 (5) { ["computedCacheControl":protected]=> array(1) { ["no-cache"]=> bool(true) } ["cookies":protected]=> array(0) { } ["headerNames":protected]=> array(2) { ["cache-control"]=> string(13) "Cache-Control" ["content-type"]=> string(12) "Content-Type" } ["headers":protected]=> array(2) { ["cache-control"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "no-cache" } ["content-type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "application/json" } } ["cacheControl":protected]=> array(0) { } } ["content":protected]=> string(21) "{"success":"success"}" ["version":protected]=> string(3) "1.0" ["statusCode":protected]=> int(200) ["statusText":protected]=> string(2) "OK" ["charset":protected]=> NULL }
```

Comment: What is `dd`? Also, you are setting the response to be the return of `response()->json['success...` so you lose the actual response, and any message it would have had. Can you do a `var_dump` on `response()->json(  ['success' => 'success'], 200 )` And edit the result into your question, for assigning it to the `$response` var

Comment: dd() is dump and die, so it kills the page right there and dumps the whole json object. I set it to success like that to make sure it was actually being hit

Comment: I think you don't need json_decode response it is already decoded... all depends on how you're accessing via ajax or some other api

Comment: var_dump on $response is NULL

Comment: @TomN. Please do the var_dump on `response()` and tell us result

Comment: @ViperTecPro you are right, when I remove that I get the actual JSON of the response with my message, but how do I change out the Success:success to be the actual message from the response

Comment: @Ice76 I've updated with that now

Comment: @TomN. just running through documentation, so it is untested, but can you do a `response()->content()` ?

Comment: This will get you're success for sure `dd(json_decode($response->content())->success);`

Comment: Also, you can get it with `->getData( true );`

Comment: @ViperTecPro I added your line below my line where I set $response and I get "success", but how do I get it to print the actual message from the endpoint?

Comment: Now i need to know how does your endpoint works ? is that some other api or ajax or something ?

Comment: It's an API I have wrapped around a call to AWS cognito. It's logging out the user so I get a json response back (i'm using guzzle to hit the endpoints)

Comment: Im unsure what youre asking, by looking at the code pasted. You should do `return response()->json('data', 200);` which returns a 200 response with `"data"` as the body.

Comment: I just want to flash the message coming back from my api call on the redirect after logging out basically @Flame

Comment: then you should flash the message and do a `redirect()->to('/yoururl')` or `redirect()->route('your.route')` to an endpoint which actually renders a blade view file that shows the flashed session data, since a `response()->json()` returns a JSON response which is not a HTML view. Both return responses but one outputs data for a user and the other outputs data for another programming interface.

Comment: Well, I have it redirecting, but I guess I'm trying to connect the two. I'm trying to show that it's returning the message by dumping so that I can then flash it on the redirect. YOur answer works, but instead of 'data' I'm just trying to get the actual response from the 200 of my guzzle request

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180515/laravel-developers come to the chat room i cant see what youre trying to do